# grep for text that may or may not be present

Tags: shell, scripting, grep, regular-expression

Lets say I have a file

```
batman;
robin;
superman;
password = "";
wonderwoman
green lantern
```

if I want to check if there is a `password` present, i.e there is something entered in the `""` . here is an example for that

```
ironman;
hulk;
spiderman;
password = "tonyStark";
black widow
hawkeye
```

How would I check if the file has a password between the `""`?

This is what I have so far

```
x=$(grep -icE "password=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]\"" file.txt)
if [ x -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "There is a password"
fi
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: It's missing a `*` so it can only match one-character passwords - in addition to the missing spaces.

Comment: Does the fact that the Justice League has no password mean that everyone has access to justice or that no-one does? Angst! ;)

Comment: Well no, the thing is I was not able to hack into batman's firewall. So The password was NULL :/
Good job batman :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if grep -q 'password = "[^"]' filename; then
    echo "password exists"
else
    echo "no password"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the whitespaces. Also negate the answer to make it more reliable

```
x=$(grep -icE "password[ ]*=[ ]*\"\"" file.txt)
if [ $x -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "There is a password"
fi
```

Comment: The white spaces may or may not be there :/ I was thinking of a cut approach

Comment: ok i modified it, so it can contain endless whitespaces between `password`, `=` and the password string `"..."`

Answer (score 0):

I would **reverse grep** "password = """.

If there is anything in the password other than empty, the filename and lines would prompt up.

Answer (score 0):

Through awk and grep,

```
awk -v var=$(grep -oP '(?<=^password = \")[^"]*' file) 'BEGIN{if (var=="") {print "There is no password"} else {print "There is a password"}}'
```

You need to run the above awk command on the directory where your input file is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
c=$(grep -iE "password"  file.txt | cut -d "\"" -f2)

if [ -z "$c" ]; then 
    echo "no password"
fi
```

is that good ?
The out put is exactly what I expected.